# display data from database using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have events table, now I want to display the most frequent element in a column using SQL

Here is the event table.

```
id  |  selectedcountries
0       | Tanzania
1       | Tanzania
2       | Tanzania
3       | Kenya
4       | Uganda
5       | Uganda
6       | Kenya
7       | Uganda
8       | Tanzania
8       | Poland
9       | Poland
10      | Tanzania
```

> UPDATE
>
> For example, for this table it should return Tanzania since it is the
>   most frequent value:

Here is my solution

```
SELECT  selectedcountries, COUNT(  'selectedcountries' ) AS  'country'
FROM EVENTS
GROUP BY  'selectedcountries'
ORDER BY  'country' DESC
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following

```
selectedcountries country
                      73
```

[image]

What do I need to do to get what I want?

Comment: I think the only problem is the quotation marks in your GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What is the version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas Apache/2.4.27 (Amazon) PHP/5.6.32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the *mode* in statistics.

You can use `group by` and `limit` if you want a single value:

```
select selectedcountries
from events
group by selectedcountries
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f7fa7c5afd2331003ac4bc7f62518e4f) is a db<>fiddle.

This does not return multiple values when there are ties.  One way to get all values for ties is two levels of aggregation:

```
select group_concat(selectedcountries)
from (select selectedcountries, count(*) as cnt
      from events
      group by selectedcountries
     ) t
group by cnt
order by cnt desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: @Strawberry your right, this does not work at all, return empty

Comment: @user9964622 . . . The code *does* work.  That is not what Strawberry is referring to.  Given your sample queries, you are probably confused by how to use quotes in SQL queries.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i tested just returns empty column

Comment: @user9964622 . . . Then the empty value has the highest count.  I added a db<>fiddle as a demonstration.

Comment: Your right, its working , I have one more question assume I have other multiple null values inside column `selectedcountry` I dont want these null or empty values to be counted, what do I need to add in that sql statement your provided in a fiddle?

Comment: @user9964622 . . . You can add `where selectedcountry is not null and selectedcountry <> ''` or even more simply just `where selectedcountry <> ''` (this removes `NULL` values as well as blank ones).

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
SELECT  selectedcountries, 
COUNT(selectedcountries) AS  'country'
FROM EVENTS 
WHERE selectedcountries <> ''
AND selectedcountries IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  selectedcountries
ORDER BY  COUNT(selectedcountries) DESC
```

Comment: check fiddle - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eaa2d45767081495b9499a95f3d34d5b

Comment: You can apply limit 1 if you need the first row only.

Comment: aah got you, for example if I have empty column and I dont want them to be counted what do I need to add in my statement?

Comment: Add WHERE selectedcountries <> '' before GROUP BY. Check updated script.

Comment: Added both Empty and NULL checking. This should work for all case.